# Role Based API with Firebase

Tags: spring, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am currently implementing an Authentication/Authorization server in Spring Boot.
I want to use Firebase Authentication to delegate the token generation, credentials and session store. 
Also, I want to secure my API urls. The app is a role based app with a microservices architecture. We actually have databases where the data is being consumed, so we cant switch to Firestore Database. In this case, there is a way to indicate Firebase if a url like '/attentions' is accesible for one role and not for another one? Do I have to implement a RBAC solution myself?
Thanks

Comment: So how does this app work?  Making requests to your backend while the user is signed in?

Comment: The user first logs into the app with his credentials, to a request to the Auth Service, which uses firebase for that approach. Then it returns a token to the user which will we used for future request to the backend. This token will be verified against firebase. But all these from my backend, which will wrap the firebase api

Comment: So the user isn't signing in with one of the authentication providers supported by Firebase SDK?  In that case, you're going to have to implement a custom auth provider.

Comment: I implemented the flow with signInWithEmailAndPassword() method which is called from my spring boot microservice. But now i want a RBAC solution for protecting the api. Can I provide this solutions with Firebase, or do i have to implement it.

Comment: If you were helped by the answer here, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do on the backend is use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to [verify a user ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) provided by the client.  Then, you can look for [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) stored in the token to determine if they should have access to some resource.